# Google App Engine - Receiving Email on a specific version

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I currently use this service to receive email on my app:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving

It is listed that the email to use is:

> string@appid.appspotmail.com

But could we target a specific version? May be something like:

> string@appid-dot-version.appspotmail.com => (mail delivery error)

It's really problematic to only be able to test this functionality on the live site without prior testing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. In the doc you linked it says:

> Mail servlets run in the default module (or application version).

You can open a [PIT Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) to add that functionality.

As a workaround maybe you could add a pattern to the target. ie in your web.xml add a filter to send all mail sent to "APP_V_DEV" be handled by a different class.